# Grails hibernate sessions opening/closing and lazy-initialization

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, lazy-loading, grails-2.0

I have a bunch of exceptions related to sessions like :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <...>, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: cannot lock an unsaved transient instance: <...>
org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists
```

I am trying to understand why.
So I have activated SQL logs, and when I look the hibernate statistics I can see like 80 sessions opened and 80 closed even if the http request is not over... 
I thought OSIV (which is activated by default in grails) could prevent some lazy-init exception stuff but, from what I see, sessions are opened then closed on demand (for transactions).

So why I don't have at least one session staying opened until the end of the http request?

Do you have any idea to understand/investigate what is happening?

Thanks a lot

```
Versions used:
    Grails 2.5.6
    GORM 3.1.4 
    Spring 4.1.9
    Hibernate3 3.6.10
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to access getter on the entity outside grails controller/service.

If you have lazily initiated relation, and you want to access it, then you should use `withTransaction` closure:

```
YourEntityClass.withTransaction{
    yourEntityClass.getX()
    // more logic
}
```

Other workarounds are:

- keep your logic in `Service`
- Use eager loading

Comment: So what you are saying is I should access my entities from sources under the controllers and services folders right under the grails-app ?
Some of my entities are referenced in sources under a folder at the same level than the two others folders (but called vms...)